# How can I add code to a libnodave test program (testISO_TCP simplified) that protects the read routine from crashing?

Tags: c, plc

I will start by saying that I am a college student with little c++ experience. How many times have you heard that right? I am working with the test program testISO_TCP (simplified version) from the libnodave library. This program does a simple read of flag values and data blocks while it is connected to a seimens 300 PLC. The program doesn't bring up any errors per se. What I am trying to do is hopefully add some code to this program that will protect the reads from ever crashing. Let me explain a little better. Say for example I have a lot of reads implemented in the code. As of now there are only two reads. Eventually I will run this code with many more reads. Now, say that I am running the test program and for some reason I lose the connection to the PLC. I would like to have the program do one of two things: 1) Once the connection is lost, do a retry connect a certain amount of times and when it runs out of tries, exit.   or  2) Somehow continue to read from the PLC until they are all done.

I hope this is enough information to get some help. I will post the code that I have been looking at for so long without any idea how to do this effectively. Thanks to all in advance.

```
#define PLAY_WITH_KEEPALIVE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "nodavesimple.h"
#include "openSocket.h"


#ifdef PLAY_WITH_KEEPALIVE
#include <winsock.h>
#endif


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a,b,c,res, doRun, doStop, doRead, doreadFlag, useProtocol, useSlot;
#ifdef PLAY_WITH_KEEPALIVE      
    int opt;
#endif    
    float d;
    daveInterface * di;
    daveConnection * dc;
    _daveOSserialType fds;
    doRun=0;
    doStop=0;
    doRead=0;
    doreadFlag=0;
    useProtocol=daveProtoISOTCP;
    useSlot=2;


 fds.rfd=openSocket(102, argv[1]);
    #ifdef PLAY_WITH_KEEPALIVE
    errno=0;    
    opt=1;
   //res=setsockopt(fds.rfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &opt, 4);
   //LOG3("setsockopt %s %d\n", strerror(errno),res);
    #endif
 fds.wfd=fds.rfd;

    if (fds.rfd>0) 
        { 
        di =daveNewInterface(fds,"IF1",0, daveProtoISOTCP, daveSpeed187k);
        daveSetTimeout(di,5000000);
        dc =daveNewConnection(di,2,0, 2);  // insert your rack and slot here



            if (0==daveConnectPLC(dc)) 
                {
                    printf("Connected.\n");

                res=daveReadBytes(dc,daveFlags,0,0,16,NULL);
                if (0==res)  
                { 
                        a=daveGetU32(dc);
                        b=daveGetU32(dc);
                        c=daveGetU32(dc);
                        d=daveGetFloat(dc);
                    printf("FD0: %d\n",a);
                    printf("FD4: %d\n",b);
                    printf("FD8: %d\n",c);
                    printf("FD12: %f\n",d);
                }//end 0==res

                }//end daveConnectPLC


            else 

            {
        printf("Couldn't connect to PLC.\n Please make sure you use the -2 option with a CP243 but not with CPs 343 or 443.\n");    
        //closeSocket(fds.rfd);
        //return -2;
            }

    }//end fds.rfd



    fds.rfd=openSocket(102, argv[1]);
    fds.wfd=fds.rfd;

    if (fds.rfd>0) 
        { 
        di =daveNewInterface(fds,"IF1",0, daveProtoISOTCP, daveSpeed187k);
        daveSetTimeout(di,5000000);
        dc =daveNewConnection(di,2,0, 2);  // insert your rack and slot here


            if (0==daveConnectPLC(dc)) 
                {
                    printf("Connected.\n");

                res=daveReadBytes(dc,daveDB,1,0,64,NULL);
                if (0==res) 
                { 

                    a=daveGetU16(dc);
                    printf("DB1:DW0: %d\n",a);
                    a=daveGetU16(dc);
                    printf("DB1:DW1: %d\n...\n",a);
                    a=daveGetU16At(dc,62);
                    printf("DB1:DW32: %d\n",a);


                }//end 0==res

                    return 0;

                }//end daveConnectPLC
            else 

            {
        printf("Couldn't connect to PLC.\n Please make sure you use the -2 option with a CP243 but not with CPs 343 or 443.\n");    
        closeSocket(fds.rfd);
        return -2;
            }

    }//end fds.rfd






    else 
    {
    printf("Couldn't open TCP port. \nPlease make sure a CP is connected and the IP address is ok. \n");    
        return -1;
    }    



}// end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the return value of the daveReadBytes function.
If it is not zero, something went wrong and you can use the daveStrerror function to get a proper error message:

`printf ("error: %s\n", daveStrerror(res));`

After that it's up to you to decide to either simply retry the read or disconnect (with closeSocket(...)) and then create a new connection from the beginning. Check the documentation on what errorcodes there are. Some errors can't be resolved by retrying (e.g. because you try reading a data block that doesn't exist).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, I have a question. How do I go about repeating the connection after the error message? I hope not to just repeat all that code (connect and read). It seems like there could be a shorter way to tell the program to repeat the code. I realize there is probably many different ways to do this, could you point me in the right direction? Thank you, again. Also, the documentation only has info on PDU error codes. Very basic info is in some of the function documentation.

Comment: Rey, things don't work that way here. You haven't rewarded any answer with an upvote and you already ask a new question inside of existing one? Both answers are valid for your question, but you ignore them and ask a new sub question just because you don't like the amount of work that you see you have to do. If that is a case, make a completely new question, but first accept answer you like most and upvote all answers that were helpfull.

Comment: Avra, let me say that first, you are right about the fact that I don't know how things work around here, since I am new. I don't have a problem voting up your answer as it was helpful, I just wasn't aware of the vote process. Secondly, I think you are wrong by saying that I don't like the amount of work I have to do. Essentially it is only a copy and paste if I did it that way. The answer was helpful, because it helped me bring up an error message according to the return values.

Comment: ***continued:        The main part of my question, is how to go about the retrying of a connection. Something that retries the connection 2 or 3 times while the internet reboots for example.... If I copy a brand new connection it won't give the downed connection enough time to reboot or re-establish. I am ready to work at it myself, I don't expect to have it written for me. Just looking for a little guidance. Thank again for your time and help.

Comment: /me shudders at the notion of a PLC connected to a rebooting internet

Comment: The code above is only good for testing and demonstrating the libnodave function calls. For a proper program you should put the whole connection establishment into a function and then check the return value of this function. Also the data retrieval should be in its own function. Then there should be your main program that first calls the connection function and then (repeatedly) the data-reading function. If any of the functions fail, the main program restarts after a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I have a loop that attempts to connect 3 times and exits gracefully if it fails
You may be able to write some other code to first check to see if the connection is up and also if the PLC is up.
Typically if you try to connect to an IP address that doesn't esond; it will hang there and tie up resources...

Answer (score 1):

I am also new programmer.But want to say that. First we have to differentiate between the `TCP/IP` connection with the `ethernet` card `ISO_TCP`. The `openSocket()` function does the connection to remote IP adress in the given port/Service (102 ISO_TCP). When called next, the function `daveNewInterface()`, it will initialise the specific interface for doing a connection to the PLC. After this, the function `daveNewConnection()` tries to open a connection on a given MPI adress, and very important, the given rack and slot. If this function returns the value 0, it will call the `daveConnectPLC()` function to connect to the PLC. At this point it´s established a ethernet connection,and also the PLC Connection.
Now you can use all the function from the **`libnodave`** library for read or write data, stop or run the PLC and much more.

In the actually simplified TCP_ISO code there are no function to disconnect the adapter or close the connection with the PLC, in your code there is the `closeSocket()` function and also the function that returns -2. Find at what line the code breaks, introducing for example a log after every function to see the returns values.

Answer (score 0):

All info for detecting loss of communication is in the documentation.

Comment: Can you tell me which of the files would have that information? Thanks

Comment: daveReadBytes.html says this: The function returns 0 on success. Nonzero return codes may be passed to daveStrerror() to get a textual explanation of what happened. Generally, positive error codes represent errors reported by the PLC, while negative ones represent errors detected by LIBNODAVE, e.g. no response from the PLC.